# create a bat file to run COD 4 Multiplayer

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I need to create a .bat file to run Call Of Duty 4 Multiplayer easily

Example using this command:

```
/connect 10.0.1.10:28960;password abcd123
```

How would I run that command?

Comment: Your title says "COD4" but you tagged it [tag:cod-advanced-warfare]. Which game are you asking about?

Comment: it must be COD4, Call_of_duty_4_Modern_Warfare

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100 % sure but I think this isn't possible. The only thing I know is that you can do quickly with is shortcuts. For example, if you want to open this site you could open that and type in 1 and this website opens. Sorry if I'm wrong but here's the shortcut code

```
@echo off
start "Program/Link To Open"
```

This should work. If I'm right just change the "program/link to open" to the program or link

Comment: @Sajith Hope this helps

Comment: thnx, but i need /connect 10.0.1.10:28960;password abcd123 to the program. tried many as ican. still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

There are ways you can run them; here is a simple code which run cod4 from .bat file you can make any adjustment as you please. You should put this in the cod4 root folder (i.e. harddisk C, D, E, F, like `C:\cod4`)

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO 1 - Run Cod4

 CHOICE /C:1

IF errorlevel 1 goto Run Cod4

:Run Cod4
start iw3mp.exe +set r_fullscreen 0 +connect 5.230.135.107:28963
ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

---